# How to have add and remove buttons in html form handle by spring 5 controller?

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 5 and Hibernate 5.
I have got form like below in jsp file:

```
<form:form action="addUser" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="name" /> <br />
                <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="email" /> <br />
                <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
            <td colspan="1"><button type="???delete???">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

And UserController.java like below:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String userForm(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
        return "editUsers";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User formBackingObject() {
        return new User();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
            return "editUsers";
        }

        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Right now I have got a submit button which allow me to save name and email of the user.
I would like to add button REMOVE which would also relay on the same form but will instead of adding new user will be removing existing user.
Could you tell how can I do it?
Maybe the first option is to add some attribute like action, but then I need to handle it in controller and I don't know how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by changing the form action dynamically based on the button click using some javascript.

```
 <script>
    $('#addBtn').click(function(){
       $("#userForm").submit(); 
    });


    $('#removeBtn').click(function(){
       $('#userForm').attr('action', '<your remove action>');
       $("#userForm").submit(); 
    });
    <script>
    <form:form action="addUser" method="post" modelAttribute="user" id="userForm">
     ...
      <td colspan="1"><button type="button" id='addBtn'>Submit</button></td>
      <td colspan="1"><button type="button" id='removeBtn'>Remove</button></td>
    ...
   </form:form>
```